# More efficient way of transforming items in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings, I needed to combined a few of the items.  Each item that would be combined is listed in consecutive order like so:

```
info = [u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00', u'B', u'0.00', u'B', u'0.00', u'%', u'0.00', u'%', u'init']

info[3] = info[3] + info[4]

info.pop(4)

info[4] = info[4] + info[5]

info.pop(5)

info[5] = info[5] + info[6]

info.pop(6)

info[6] = info[6] + info[7]

info.pop(7)

>>> info
[u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00B', u'0.00B', u'0.00%', u'0.00%', u'init']
```

The last line being the desired output but, I wanted to get some ideas of a better way without all the popping and assignment?

UPDATE:  Wow! These are all great, I want to test and time them all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution

```
>>> info[:3] + [''.join(e) for e in zip(info[3::2],info[4::2])] + info[-1:]
[u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00B', u'0.00B', u'0.00%', u'0.00%', u'init']
```

Comment: I think you want your first slice to be `info[:3]` or you'll lose the `"root"` string.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to solve this kind of issue, where you're processing a sequence of items and want to create a new sequence, is to use a generator function. This one will work, I think:

```
def combine_items(seq):
    it = iter(seq) # get an iterator

    yield next(it) # yield the first three items unmodified
    yield next(it)
    yield next(it)

    while True: # run until there's an exception
        first = next(it) # grab the first item in a pair
        try:
            second = next(it) # grab the second
            yield first + second # yield the combined pair
        except StopIteration: # if the second was off the end of the sequence
            yield first  # yield the first item unmodified
            raise # and reraise the exception to exit
```

The `while` loop runs until the sequence is completely consumed. When there are no more items, `next` raises a `StopIteration` which we will let propagate out, since that's the signal that an generator is done.

To get the output in a list, just wrap a call to the generator in the `list` constructor:

```
>>> list(combine_items(info))
['1', 'be/4', 'root', '0.00B', '0.00B', '0.00%', '0.00%', 'init']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a rather simple method is just:

```
>>> lst[:] = lst[:3] + [lst[3] + lst[4], lst[5] + lst[6], lst[7] + lst[8], lst[9] + lst[10], lst[11]] + [lst[11]]
[u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00B', u'0.00B', u'0.00%', u'0.00%', u'init']
```

This just constructs a new list from the existing list, then makes `lst` be that new list.

Could write some snazzy function that deals with the pairings though...

And to make it clearer, you could format the code to be something like,

```
lst[:] = (
    lst[:3] +
    [
        lst[3] + lst[4],
        lst[5] + lst[6],
        lst[7] + lst[8],
        lst[9] + lst[10]
    ] +
    [lst[11]]
)
```

Which makes it fairly clear where the slicing, pairings and endings are...

Another option which move single characters fields but not extensively tested:

```
>>> text = '\t'.join(lst)
>>> re.sub('\t(.)\t', r'\1\t', text).split('\t') # or use ([B%]) instead maybe
[u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00B', u'0.00B', u'0.00%', u'0.00%', u'init']
```

Comment: Now try it with 10000 items

Comment: @JBernardo - sure if the pairings were predictable, then a function, but then I'd want the rules for 10000 items and it looks like the OP is process some `ps` style output so I doubt they'll be too many columns... Like I say, this is a "simple method", but remains explicit and understable, without popping etc...

Comment: @JonClements I like that this is clean and clear on where the pairings are.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> to_join = iter(info[3:-1])

>>> info[:3] + [x + next(to_join) for x in to_join] + info[-1:]
[u'1', u'be/4', u'root', u'0.00B', u'0.00B', u'0.00%', u'0.00%', u'init']
```